# Dealing with missing values when converting a list of dictionaries into a dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary, missing-data

Is there a way to deal with missing values when converting a `list` of `dictionaries` into a pandas `dataframe`? Sometimes the `dictionary` entries in different orders so I have to deal with each column separately.

Here is an example:

```
p = [
 {'c': 53.13,'n': 1,'t': 1575050400000},
 {'t': 1575048600000,'c': 53.11}
  ]
```

And here is what I have been trying:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{
        "c": t["c"],
        "n": t["n"],
        "t": t['t']}
        for t in p])
```

I get a `KeyError: 'n'` because the entry for 'n' is missing in the second `dictionary`. Is there a way of handling that to just put a `NaN` when the entry is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a DataFrame from `p` as an argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(p)
df
```

Output:

```
       c    n              t
0  53.13  1.0  1575050400000
1  53.11  NaN  1575048600000
```

Comment: sorry i deleted my comment because it was obvious from your output.

Comment: @helloimgeorgia Yes, makes sense :) deleted mine as well then to avoid confusion

Comment: @helloimgeorgia In fact, you don't even need `from_dict` here; just using `pd.DataFrame(p)` would do the same thing; updated my answer